# How can I pass the argument in the bash script as an argument without quotation marks?

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a="$1"
awk "BEGIN { print $a }"
```

If I run the script like this:

```
script.sh "(1+1)"
```

I'll get this back as a result: 2

I want to achieve the same without quotation marks.
If I run the script like this(without quotation marks):

```
script.sh (1+1)
```

Throws an error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `script.sh \(1+1\)` Remember you need to escape space as well, for example `\(1\ +\ 2\)`

Comment: Parentheses are special to bash. You need to quote or escape them so bash doesn't interpret them and passes them forward literally.